# Clean Code: Dependency Injection forces procedural code, how to refactor

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, ooad

I have the below classes:

```
  class Validator {
    private final SchemaFetcher schemaFetcher;

    @Inject
    Validator(SchemaFetcher schemaFetcher) {...}
  }

  class DatabaseSchemaFetcher implements SchemaFetcher {
     @Override
     Schema loadSchema(final SchemaDefinition schemaDef);

     @Override
     boolean compareSchemaWithSource(final SchemaDefinition schemaDef, final Schema updatedSchema);
  }
```

This is just one of the examples, I have some other classes like this which I inject into other classes as dependencies. But it makes my SchemaFetcher class like a singleton and I keep passing the schemaDefinition to every single method of it. This seems very procedural and I want to actually make SchemaDefinition an instance variable to the DatabaseSchemaFetcher class but in that case I would not be able to inject a SchemaFetcher Object into my Validator class and instead I should be doing

```
   validate(String schemaName) {
     SchemaDefinition schemaDef = buildSchemaDefinitionFrom(schemaName);
     SchemaFetcher fetcher = new DatabaseSchemaFetcher(schemaDef);
   }
```

But this makes me tightly coupled to the fetcher which is why I wanted to use Dependency Injection in the first place.

I can see that I could possibly have a default constructor for DatabaseSchemaFetcher and then a setSchemaDefintion() setter to acheive this but that violates the principle of building your object completely using the constructor.

How do I improve this to not have a procedural style fetcher but also inject my dependencies into the constructor? I prefer constructor injection because it clearly defines my dependencies without anyone looking into the implementation of the class to figure out the dependencies the class uses if I use a factory or service locator.

Comment: My advice is to relax your strong preference for constructor injection. For one they don't allow circular dependencies; for another they don't allow injection of lazily initialized objects (achievable with lookup methods).

Answer (score 5):

Dependency Injection is one of those very good ideas that seems so good that it gets badly overused.  I would not inject the Fetcher into the Validator using the DI framework.  Rather, I'd have the DI framework inject a factory into "main".  The factory creates the Fetcher with the appropriate SchemaDefinition and passes it to the Validator.

Remember that we want a boundary separating "main" from the rest of the application, and all dependencies should point from "main" to the application.  The application should not know about "main".  i.e. "main" is a plugin to the application.

In general, DI should be used to inject into "main", and then main uses more traditional techniques to pass factories, strategies, or just regular old abstract interfaces into the application.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say you're tightly coupled to SchemaFetcher in your 2nd solution? 
You're providing there an interface, so you're not coupled to any specific implementation, but  only to the definition of what SchemaFetcher is (i.e - the contract of the SchemaFetcher) 
You may consider to have a Validator class which takes into its CTOR the SchemaDefinition, and  your DatabaseSchemaFetcher can hold a field to it. This way you will also be able to extend the Validator class change the validation logic if required. 
But once again, the question of how to pass the schema definition object rises. Not sure injection should be used here - consider altering your design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the use of `Dependecy Injection` and `Procedural` have to do with each other in this instance.

I think the real issue is that the way you've chosen to model you're objects does not reflect the stated goal.

In the code you've supplied `Validator` serves no purpose that I can see. If its purpose is to validate `SchemaFetcher` objects then it probably should have no state beyond the rules for validation then accept arbitary `SchemaFetcher` objects to validate.

As for `DataBaseSchemaFetcher` I once again struggle to understand what this does. If its stated purpose is only to fetch schemas then it requires no state in regards to `DatabaseSchema` objects and as such should accept `DatabaseSchema` for the methods in which it is charged with acting on a `DatabaseSchema`. Any internal state should only be related to the classes's fetching behavior.

One tried and true way to get past these `painted in a corner` situations is to sit down and try really hard to assign each class a single responsibility and keep in mind the following:

1. Thing really hard about the domain of the exact problem you are trying to solve.
2. Do not solve any problems you don't have.Take your dreams of extensibility and throw them away. They will almost always be wrong and will just be a huge time sink.
3. Accept that your design is necessarily deficient and you will have to change it later.